# Laravel photo uploader class

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to separate logic from the controller, so I created this `Upload` class. It is not a big class, just a class so that the controller doesn't know about the logic and stuff like that.

```
<?php 
namespace Dnianas\Uploads;

class Photo 
{    

    /**
     * The image filename.
     * @var string
     */
    protected $filename;

    /**
     * The image extension.
     * @var string
     */
    protected $extension;

    /**
     * The image hashed value that we hashed using SHA1.
     * @var string
     */
    protected $hashedName;

    /**
     * The filename with the hashed name and the extension.
     * @var string
     */
    public $path;

    public function makeProfilePicture($input)
    {
        $this->fileName     = $input->getClientOriginalName();
        $this->extension    = $input->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $this->hashedName   = sha1(time() . $this->fileName);
        $this->path         = $this->hashedName . '.' .$this->extension;

        // Resize the image
        $image = \Image::make($input);
        $image->fit(300, 300);

        // Set the destination
        $destination = photos_path() . '/' . $this->path;

        // Save the image
        $image->save($destination);

        // Return the object
        return $this;
    }

    public function makeCoverPhoto($input)
    {
        $this->fileName     = $input->getClientOriginalName();
        $this->extension    = $input->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $this->hashedName   = sha1(time() . $this->fileName);
        $this->path         = $this->hashedName . '.' .$this->extension;

        // Resize the image
        $image = \Image::make($input);
        $image->fit(900, 350);

        // Set the destination
        $destination = photos_path() . '/cover-' . $this->path;

        // Save the image
        $image->save($destination);

        return $this;
    }

}
```

As you can see, the first 4 lines from each method is exactly the same. How can I improve this?

**EDIT**: I've followed the constructor method. I added the constructor.

Here is the final class:

```
<?php 
namespace Dnianas\Uploads;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class Photo 
{    

    /**
     * The image filename.
     * @var string
     */
    protected $filename;

    /**
     * The image extension.
     * @var string
     */
    protected $extension;

    /**
     * The image hashed value that we hashed using SHA1.
     * @var string
     */
    protected $hashedName;

    /**
     * The filename with the hashed name and the extension.
     * @var string
     */
    public $path;

    /**
     * The input from the user, Usually it's the file.
     * @var object
     */
    public $input;

    public function __construct(UploadedFile $input)
    {
        $this->input        = $input;
        $this->fileName     = $this->input->getClientOriginalName();
        $this->extension    = $this->input->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $this->hashedName   = sha1(time() . $this->fileName);
        $this->path         = $this->hashedName . '.' .$this->extension;
    }

    public function makeProfilePicture()
    {
        // Resize the image
        $image = \Image::make($this->input);
        $image->fit(300, 300);

        // Set the destination
        $destination = photos_path() . '/' . $this->path;

        // Save the image
        $image->save($destination);

        // Return the object
        return $this;
    }

    public function makeCoverPhoto()
    {
        // Resize the image
        $image = \Image::make($this->input);
        $image->fit(900, 350);

        // Set the destination
        $destination = photos_path() . '/cover-' . $this->path;

        // Save the image
        $image->save($destination);

        return $this;
    }

}
```

And in the controllers I do this:

```
$profilePicture = (new Photo($input))->makeProfilePicture();
```

Comment: Try using a constructor?

Comment: I guess this is how we all learn ;). You're welcome. See answer below for a couple of suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a constructor. I'm pretty sure you can type hint your dependency too, so long as you know what you're working with, you can adjust to your needs.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class Photo {    

    protected $fileName;
    protected $extension;
    protected $hashedName;
    protected $path;

    public function __construct(UploadedFile $input)
    {
        $this->fileName     = $input->getClientOriginalName();
        $this->extension    = $input->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $this->hashedName   = sha1(time() . $this->fileName);
        $this->path         = $this->hashedName . '.' .$this->extension;
    }

    // methods...

}
```

Please also note in your code you wrote `protected $filename;` then referenced back to that in your methods as `$this->fileName` - make sure you get the `n` or `N` consistent.

You can always make a getter for the `path` attribute instead of making it `public` keep it `protected`.

```
public function getPath()
{
    return $this->path;
}
```

Hope that helps!